# Enumerating columns of large data using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large data, and I want to name the columns, for instance '1', '2', ... . For a small data, I can do

```
np.random.randint(5, size=(50, 2))   # synthesis data
A = A.ravel().view([('1','i8'),('2','i8'),]).astype([('1','i4'),('2','i8'),])
```

and then call an individual column using

```
print(A['2'])
```

I was wondering if there is a way to automate this for any random size and column numbers. My preference is to use NumPy, not Pandas. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending from your work, you can use a list comprehension to accomplish this. It will automatically create the required number of columns with the proper labels:

```
A = np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 10))
B = A.ravel().view([ (str(x),'i4') for x in range(1, len(A[0])+1) ])
```

Then you can do `print(A['2'])` from 1 to 10 in this case.

Comment: @Blade. You are right. I did, should have earlier, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas would make a good job of this, so if your only reason to avoid it is so you don't need to get to grips with another library, it may be worth your time learning Pandas so you can use it in future.

An alternative is xarray, which handles n-dimensional data.
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/

You can name both the axes (e.g. calling one "time") and the values in them (e.g. calling a particular point on the time axis "start").  You could then slice out all the data that has value "start" on the "time" axis.